# Rails: selecting random users except current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I'm trying to select some random users using the [`randumb`](https://github.com/spilliton/randumb) gem. My controller code looks like this:

`@random_users = User.order_by_rand.limit(3).all`

This search currently includes the `current_user` in the random results. How can I exclude it ? i've tried insering an extra condition `id: !current_user.id`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude a record from your query by using [NOT SQL queries](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions).

```
User.where.not(id: current_user.id).order_by_rand.limit(3)
```

And if this is going to be reusable, you can go ahead and create a simple scope like below:

```
# user.rb

# ex: User.exluding(current_user).order_by_rand....
scope :excluding, (lambda do |user|
  return all unless user.present?
  where.not(id: user.id)
end)
```

The folks at Thoughtbot also have a [great article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecords-wherenot) on these types of queries.

**Update** from your comment below:

To exclude followers:

```
# user.rb

# This will also exclude the user you pass in.
# so you will not need to chain the original scope `excluding`.
scope :recommended_users, (lambda do |user|
  return all unless user.present?
  where.not(id: user.following_ids << user.id)
end)
```

Comment: That works, but how about also finding users who the current user is not following ? I'm trying something like `.followers.include(!current_user)` but that doesn't seem to work. Do I have to iterate over each user, as in `do |user| ...` ? I'm using the `acts_as_follower` gem here

Comment: @omegalo, see updated answer. This assumed you have a relationship, `following`, that represents the users a user is following.

Comment: This seems to exclude the current user, but `following_ids` returns nil in the console, despite following 2 other users; the users i'm following still show up.. any ideas ?